# expression must have a constant value on BT_GATT_SERVICE_DEFINE

Tags: nrf52, zephyr-rtos

I was following [this demo](https://michaelangerer.dev/zephyr/2022/04/07/zephyr-basics-ble-1.html) and trying to set up BT_GATT_SERVICE_DEFINE on VSCode using nRF Connect and adapt it for the nRF52 DK (52832) I keep getting the following error:

```
expression must have a constant value
```

Here is where I am getting the error:

```
BT_GATT_SERVICE_DEFINE(
    led_svc, BT_GATT_PRIMARY_SERVICE(&led_svc_uuid),
    BT_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC(&led_state_char_uuid.uuid,
                           BT_GATT_CHRC_READ | BT_GATT_CHRC_WRITE,
                           BT_GATT_PERM_READ | BT_GATT_PERM_WRITE,
                           read_led_state, write_led_state, &led_state), );
```

I'm not sure what it means but I seem to be running it frequently whenever I try to adapt the code. Here is the rest of the code:

```
#include <zephyr/types.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <zephyr/sys/printk.h>
#include <zephyr/sys/byteorder.h>
#include <zephyr/kernel.h>
#include <zephyr/settings/settings.h>

#include <zephyr/bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/conn.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/uuid.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/gatt.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/services/bas.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/services/hrs.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/services/ias.h>

#include <zephyr/drivers/gpio.h>

//#include "services/ewblesvc.h"

// LED Device
#define LED DT_NODELABEL(led0)
static const struct gpio_dt_spec led = GPIO_DT_SPEC_GET(LED, gpios);

static uint8_t led_state = false;

void main(void) {
  // make sure the LED device is ready
  if (!device_is_ready(led.port)) {
    return;
  }
  gpio_pin_configure_dt(&led, GPIO_OUTPUT);
  gpio_pin_set_dt(&led, led_state);
}

// Service and Characteristics UUIDs
static struct bt_uuid_128 led_state_char_uuid = BT_UUID_INIT_128(
    BT_UUID_128_ENCODE(0x9c85a726, 0xb7f1, 0x11ec, 0xb909, 0x0242ac120002));

#define LED_SERVICE_UUID_VAL \
  BT_UUID_128_ENCODE(0xf7547938, 0x68ba, 0x11ec, 0x90d6, 0x0242ac120003)

static struct bt_uuid_128 led_svc_uuid =
    BT_UUID_INIT_128(LED_SERVICE_UUID_VAL);


// Advertisement Data
static const struct bt_data ad[] = {
    BT_DATA_BYTES(BT_DATA_FLAGS, (BT_LE_AD_GENERAL | BT_LE_AD_NO_BREDR)),
    BT_DATA_BYTES(BT_DATA_UUID128_ALL, LED_SERVICE_UUID_VAL),
};

BT_GATT_SERVICE_DEFINE(
    led_svc, BT_GATT_PRIMARY_SERVICE(&led_svc_uuid),
    BT_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC(&led_state_char_uuid.uuid,
                           BT_GATT_CHRC_READ | BT_GATT_CHRC_WRITE,
                           BT_GATT_PERM_READ | BT_GATT_PERM_WRITE,
                           read_led_state, write_led_state, &led_state), );


static void connected(struct bt_conn *conn, uint8_t err) {
  if (err) {
    printk("Connection failed (err 0x%02x)\n", err);
  } else {
    printk("Connected\n");
  }
}

static void disconnected(struct bt_conn *conn, uint8_t reason) {
  printk("Disconnected (reason 0x%02x)\n", reason);
}

BT_CONN_CB_DEFINE(conn_callbacks) = {
    .connected = connected,
    .disconnected = disconnected,
};

static ssize_t read_led_state(struct bt_conn *conn,
                             const struct bt_gatt_attr *attr, void *buf,
                             uint16_t len, uint16_t offset) {
  const uint8_t *val = attr->user_data;
  printk("Value 0x%x read.\n", *val);
  return bt_gatt_attr_read(conn, attr, buf, len, offset, val, sizeof(*val));
}

static ssize_t write_led_state(struct bt_conn *conn,
                              const struct bt_gatt_attr *attr, const void *buf,
                              uint16_t len, uint16_t offset, uint8_t flags) {
  uint8_t *val = attr->user_data;
  *val = *((uint8_t *)buf);

  printk("Value 0x%x written.\n", *val);
  printk("Current LED state %s - turning LED %s\n", led_state ? "off" : "on",
         led_state ? "on" : "off");

  gpio_pin_set_dt(&led, led_state);
  return len;
}
```